# How to convert a uint to 64 byte hex string using Node.js?

Tags: nodejs

Sir,
   If my uint is 10,how to convert 10 to '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a' by using Node.js? and reverse it from '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a' to uint 10 ?

Answer (score 2):

> Sir, If my uint is 10,how to convert 10 to
>   '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a'
>   by using Node.js?

You can use `web3.toHex(number)` to convert decimal number to hex then using `web3.utils.padLeft("0x0abcdef", 64)` to format the hex string to a 64 byte length hex

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#padleft

> and reverse it from
>   '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a'
>   to uint 10 ?

just simply use `web3.toDecimal()` function to convert any hex string to decimal

Answer (score 0):

Got it. My example is：

```
var a = 10
console.log(a); //output ：10
var b = web3.utils.toHex(a);  
console.log(b); //output ：0xa
var c = web3.utils.padLeft(b, 64);
console.log(c);  //output ：0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a
var d = web3.utils.toDecimal(c)
console.log(d); //output ：10
```